# MVC Invidual Accounts and WebAPI Azure AD

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory

I know this will bring opinion but I'm looking for more a direction.

I have a plan to build a WebAPI that will serve two clients.

Client 1 will be a MVC web app and will use Individual accounts to authenticate users on the site. This is the customer facing client. Cuistomers login, make orders, etc... (Maybe Social logins later)

Client 2 will be more of the back-end and will support orders, inventory, shipping, etc...I haven't decided on MVC or WPF yet. No customers will see this side. I was thinking of using Azure AD.

Each client will utilize a WebAPI that will make most of the related DB calls and services. That way I can write the code once and service both clients.

```
-------------         ------------
| DB Layer  |   -->   | WEB API  |    -->   Website (Customer)
| AZURE DB  |         |  AZURE   |    -->   Client (Employee, Backend)
-------------         ------------
```

So the question is can I use Indivudal accounts for the customer site and then use Azure AD for the employee side? Also, authentication on the webapi side would be azure if I'm using Azure to host this correct?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Look at [Azure AD B2C](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/active-directory-b2c/).  It's designed for exactly this sort of scenario and supports social logins as well as AD integration.  There are a few little bits and pieces that need some polish (primarily documentation, but some up-to-date sample code would also go a long way), however it is in active development and seems to work fairly well for most purposes.

Comment: I agree B2C is a good fit for the customer-facing site. Though maybe using regular Azure AD for the Employee client might be better. Then the Web API would need to accept tokens for two different audiences, but that would be the way I would do it.

Comment: @juunas I haven't tried it yet, "with custom policies (in public preview), Azure AD B2C can federate to Azure AD allowing authentication of employees in an organization" (from this [outdated FAQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-faqs)). [This page](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuredev/2017/05/30/azure-ad-b2c-kicking-it-up-a-notch-with-support-for-aad-as-idp/) has some good info.

Comment: Custom policies are pretty hard.. It's possible but hard. But yeah they do allow that scenario.